# Can I create Zeppelin visualizations through the REST API?

Tags: rest, visualization, apache-zeppelin

I have a requirement where I want to create barcharts and piecharts in Zeppelin notebook without direct user interaction. I see that the notebook API supports providing paragraph text in the form of json. I tried providing it json of an existing notebook that has barchart, however, I don't see it getting created in the new notebook. Does anyone know if Zeppelin supports this functionality?

Comment: Hi, Did you found any solution? , Currently I am updating the paragraph and  running the paragraph synchronously but I couldn't see any changes in the IFrame or the paragraph retrieved from api(get paragraph api).

Comment: @Vinujan.S These changes have been made in Zeppelin, and will be available in version 0.8.0. See following: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2106

Comment: thank you for the reply. Eagerly waiting for the release

Comment: If you are using Spark and wanna create chart, then it does not have connection with Zeppelin. Check https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/ which can create self contain html chart with all interactive abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest API to create charts in Zeppelin will be available in version 0.8.0.